# Why PHP 4.4.9 throws 'Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STATIC'?

Tags: php, php4, syntax-error

I just realized the professor Google is unable to present a specific page where I can find out, when `static` keyword added to PHP 4. Though following the [change log for php 4](http://php.net/ChangeLog-4.php) I can see that it was available since Version 4.0.6 (or before) but why does it throws:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STATIC, expecting T_OLD_FUNCTION or T_FUNCTION or T_VAR or '}' in {FILE_PATH+LINE#}

for a simple code as follows:

```
class myClass
{
    static $_debug = true;
}
```

Or this assignment of class-variable was introduced in earlier versions of PHP?

Comment: What you see in the PHP 4 changelog are references to static methods, not the `static` keyword.

Comment: for those who doubt if static is something specific to php5.x, checkout http://www.sfr-fresh.com/unix/www/php-4.4.9.tar.gz:a/php-4.4.9/Zend/zend_language_parser.c

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm pretty sure static class variables are new to PHP5, so can't be used in PHP4.

Here's the deal: PHP4 can use the `static` keyword in *functions*, not classes. The only PHP4 usage of `static` was like this:

```
function howManyTimes() {
    static $count = 0;
    echo "Function has been called $count times.";
    $count++;
}
```

That variable is bound to the function's scope forever. That's how PHP4 interprets `static`. The PHP5 interpretation you are trying to use is not available in your current PHP version. Sorry!

Comment: +1 Yup - public/private/protected and static are PHP 5 only I believe.

Comment: True that. Static is PHP 5 specific.

Comment: http://www.sfr-fresh.com/unix/www/php-4.4.9.tar.gz:a/php-4.4.9/Zend/zend_language_parser.c

Comment: ...I'm confused as to what that link is for. Are you saying I'm wrong?

Comment: Thanks for the answer and for all of the participants. Infact, like most of the functions PHP guys should have clearly mentioned it somewhere.

I just downloaded the php 4.4.9 and checked my self and php 4.4.9 was like yaikh! no static keyword was recognized there.

Regards!!